# Regex: capture paired curly braces

Tags: php, regex

I want to capture matched curly braces.

**For example**:

`Some example text with \added[author]{text with curly braces{some text}..}`

`Some example text with \added[author]{text without curly braces}`

`Some example text with \added[author]{text with {}and {} and {}curly braces{some text}..}`

`Some example text with \added[author]{text with {}and {} and {}curly braces{some text}..} and extented text with curly braces {}`

**Expected output:**

`Some example text with text with curly braces{some text}..`

`Some example text with text without curly braces`

`Some example text with text with {}and {} and {}curly braces{some text}..`

`Some example text with text with {}and {} and {}curly braces{some text}.. and extented text with curly braces {}`

i.e. I want to capture the text between `\added[]{` and `}`(its relative closing curly braces).Problem with my regex is, I don't know how to  capture between the related curly braces.

I tried,

```
       "/\\\\added\\[.*?\\]{(.[^{]*?)}/s"
```

I know it ignores if `{` present in the text. But I don't get an idea how to create a regex to get matched curly braces alone.

Comment: Please guys help me with my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33841196/how-to-match-text-inside-starting-and-closing-curly-brace-the-tags-and-the-spec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match paired braces you'll want to use a [recursive subpattern](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php).

---

**Example:**

```
$regex = <<<'REGEX'
/
\\added\[.*?\]                # Initial \added[author]

(                             # Group to be recursed on.
    {                         # Opening brace.

    (                         # Group for use in replacement.

        ((?>[^{}]+)|(?1))*    # Any number of substrings which can be either:
                              # - a sequence of non-braces, or
                              # - a recursive match on the first capturing group.
    )

    }                         # Closing brace.
)
/xs
REGEX;

$strings = [
    'Some example text with \added[author]{text with curly braces{some text}..}',
    'Some example text with \added[author]{text without curly braces}',
    'Some example text with \added[author]{text with {}and {} and {}curly braces{some text}..}',
    'Some example text with \added[author]{text with {}and {} and {}curly braces{some text}..} and extented text with curly braces {}'
];

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    echo preg_replace($regex, '$2', $string), "\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
Some example text with text with curly braces{some text}..
Some example text with text without curly braces
Some example text with text with {}and {} and {}curly braces{some text}..
Some example text with text with {}and {} and {}curly braces{some text}.. and extented text with curly braces {}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. Can you please explain this regex?

Answer (score 3):

Here, should work

```
/\\added\[.*\]\{(.*(?:.*\{.*\}.*)*)\}/gU
```

**Explanation**

`/\\added\` is a Latex tag,

`\[.*\]` is an option of Latex tag,

`\{` open bracket,

`(.*(?:.*\{.*\}.*)*)` is captured text which here we also prevent for recursive `{...}` or multiple `{...}` inside our target tag,

`\}` close bracket.

**Strategy**

I do not consider pair of bracket as a recursive form

```
{ { {...} } }
c b a   a b c
```

where we have pair `a`, `b` and `c`,

but I consider them like this!

```
{ { {...} } }   
a b c   a b c
```

see: [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vX3bH4/1)

The last two examples in my demo also prove that it work correctly.

**IMPORTANT:** the modifier `U` suppose to be used here for a purpose of non-greedy quantifier otherwise my regex will not work correctly.

Comment: It works! Thank you. Shall I know which regex would be the effective way?with or without recursion?

Comment: My regex doesn't require even `lookaround`, just an straightforward pattern. Hope you satisfy with it!

Comment: I'm going to use a simple regex pattern itself

Comment: @Learning I added some idea that I used to solve this problem, hope it help you to understand more about my regex.

Comment: So, its like counting the open and closing curly braces?

Comment: @Learning Its sound like that but if you consider them as recursive brackets you won't able to match brackets pair by pair because your regex expanding from left to right not inside out, that's the main idea.

Comment: Can you check here https://regex101.com/r/vX3bH4/2?  In this case it is not working properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88494/discussion-between-terces907-and-learning).

Answer (score 1):

use following regex :

```
\\\\added\\[[^\\]]\*][^\\{]\*{((?:(?:[^\\{\\}]\*\\{[^\\}\\{]\*\\})\*||[^\\}]\*)\*)}
```

Comment: What if  `Some example text with \added[author]{text with {}and {} and {}curly braces{some text}..} and extented text with curly braces {}` ? In this case, output should be like, `Some example text with text with {}and {} and {}curly braces{some text}.. and extented text with curly braces {}` Problem is, it captures till the last curly braces, it doesn't capture till matched curly braces

Answer (score 0):

Use this **`regex`**

```
/\\added[^]]*]{([^}]*}[^}]*)}/s
```

**[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/eM5zU4/1)**

Comment: Thank you!  It works only for the example which i have given..but regex aim is to get matched curly braces. Please refer my updated post for more examples.