# How to match text inside starting and closing curly brace, the tags and the specified attributes

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am implementing a plugin code for my CMS system. Something like a shortcode but will be applicable in many scenarios. I want a case where an admin writes his code like this:

**Example 1:**

`{COMMAND_NAME}Strings of texts that conatains htmltags,symbols,just anything{/COMMAND_NAME}`

**Example 2**

`{COMMAND_NAME}`

**Example 3**

`{COMMAND_NAME{attriute1=value attribute2=value}}`

**Example 4**

`{COMMAND_NAME{attriute1=value attribute2=value}}Strings of anything including texts, htmltags and anything at all {/COMMAND_NAME}`

Regex can match the the above string. Get the `COMMAND_NAME`, get the text in between and get the closing `{/COMMAND_NAME}` from a single regex pattern.

In the regex , I want to capture the `COMMAND_NAME`, the attributes if provided, the text in between if the `{COMMAND_NAME}` has a closing `{/COMMAND_NAME}` and the closing `{/COMMAND_NAME}` if provided.

**See what I've done so far and go some incomplete result.**

```
$regex = #\{(RAW|ACCESS|DWNLINK|MODL)[\{]{0,1}([\w\W\s]*?)\}{0}\}([\w\s]+)([\{/RAW|ACCESS|DWNLINK|MODL]*)\}#i

$strings = '<div class="blog-list-item blog"><header class="entry-title">
        <h1>Welcome to our website</h1>
    </header><article id="entry-72" class="entry post-72 page et-bg-layout-dark et-white-bg"><div class="jumbotron row">
<div class="col-md-8">
<ul>
<li>You have a pending job on your neck?&hellip;</li>
<li>Do your company need a website makeover ?&hellip;</li>
<li>Or a competitive web application ? ?&hellip;</li>
<li>Do you need a customized plugin, or a tweak ?&hellip;</li>
<li>Maybe you want a personal website ?&hellip;</li>
<li>Or a graphic for your new project ?&hellip;</li>
</ul>
<div class="bg-primary well">
<h4 class="text-center text-white shadow">Track your project as we work it         to perfection...</h4>
</div>
</div>
<div class="pull-right col-md-4">
<h4 class="bg-primary text-white well">Other services we offer</h4>
{ACCESS{type=500}}
<ul>
<li>SEO work for an existing website or new</li>
<li>Bulk SMS</li>
<li>E-currency exchange</li>
<li>Facebook AD</li>
<li>Google AD</li>
</ul>
{/ACCESS}</div>
{RAW{say=email,access=500}} {RAW} <a class="btn button large tall green"     href="client-area">Place new Job now as we deliver at the quickest   <em>reasonable time</em></a>{/RAW}</div></article></div>';

And doing a php var_dump, gives the following result:
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(224) "{ACCESS{type=500}}
<ul>
<li>SEO work for an existing website or new</li>
<li>Bulk SMS</li>
<li>E-currency exchange</li>
<li>Facebook AD</li>
<li>Google AD</li>
</ul>
{/ACCESS}</div>
{RAW{say=email,access=500}} {RAW}"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "ACCESS"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(209) "type=500}}
<ul>
<li>SEO work for an existing website or new</li>
<li>Bulk SMS</li>
<li>E-currency exchange</li>
<li>Facebook AD</li>
<li>Google AD</li>
</ul>
{/ACCESS}</div>
{RAW{say=email,access=500}"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) " "
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "{RAW"
  }
}
```

Which is actually not what i needed to retrieve.
Once again, I want to capture the `COMMAND_NAME`, the attributes only if provided, the text in between if the `{COMMAND_NAME}` has a closing `{/COMMAND_NAME}` and the closing `{/COMMAND_NAME}` if provided. That means the command can be inline `{COMMAND_NAME}`, or not `{COMMAND_NAME}` some strings `{/COMMAND_NAME}`, has an attribute `{COMMAND_NAME{attr1=value attr2=value2}}` or not.

Comment: While you don't need something as complex as the tags used with Wikipedia, you could also have a look over the [MediaWiki Parser.php](https://git.wikimedia.org/blob/mediawiki%2Fcore.git/master/includes%2Fparser%2FParser.php) source.

Comment: @Tigger Good point, I had no idea it follows wiki tags syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will work as you specified:

```
$regex = '~

#opening tag
\{(RAW|ACCESS|DWNLINK|MODL|\w+)
 #optional attributes
 (?>
     \{   ([^}]*)   }
 )?

}


#optional text and closing tag
(?:
    (   #text:= any char except "{", or a "{" not followed by /commandname
        [^{]*+
        (?>\{(?!/?\1[{}])[^{]*)*+
    )

    #closing tag
    (   \{/\1}   )
)?

~ix';
```

<kbd>[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/hH2pH4/4)</kbd>

---

**Compared to what you had:**

First of all, I used the `/x` modifier (at the end), which ignores whitespace and `#comments`.

In the opening tag, I used your options, but you may as well use `\w+` to match *any* command name:

```
\{(RAW|ACCESS|DWNLINK|MODL|\w+)
```

For the optional attributes, you had `[\{]{0,1}([\w\W\s]*?)\}{0}`, which was avalid attempt to make every part optional. Instead, I'm using a `(?> group )?` (See [non-capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and [atomic groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html)) to make the whole subpattern optional (with the `?` [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)).

```
 (?>
     \{   ([^}]*)   }
 )?
```

The same logic is applied to the text and closing tag, to make it optional.

You were using `[\w\s]+` to match the text, which matches word characters and whitespace, but fails to match punctuation and other characters. I could have used `.*?` and it would work just as fine. However, I used the following construct, which matches the same, but performs better:

```
    (   #text:= any char except "{", or a "{" not followed by /commandname
        [^{]*+
        (?>\{(?!/?\1[{}])[^{]*)*?
    )
```

And finally, I'm matching the closing tag using `\1`, which is a backreference to the text matched in group 1 (the opening tag name):

```
\{/\1}
```

---

Assumptions:

- An attribute does not have a closing brace in quotes such as `"te}xt"` that could make it break.

Comment: Mariano you happened to save my day! Believe me, you saved me. Regex is one thing i always stumble on whenever am handling a project. And i cant just help the frustration it gives me each time. Thanks once again.

Comment: Please can you modify your solution to include capturing the closing {/COMMAND_NAME} tag. Reason is because some of the commands may come as inline e,g {MODL{name=module_name,title=title of the module,access=access_rule}} which is a module replacement. Unlike ACCESS which depends on the text in between .Thanks once again.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. I thought there wasn't a reason to capture the closing tag because you'd only have one if you have a match for the text (group 2)

Comment: Okay . but i neeeded the closing tag group i.e {/COMMAD_NAME} is exist. Meaning it is optional. Some COMMANDS are inline. So a block commands replacement will happen on the text in betweeen while inline tag will just replace the COMMAND declaration. Hope you understand

Comment: I still think you don't need it, but I've already edited the code before your comment. Enjoy :)