# What is this {}{/} curly brace syntax?

Tags: syntax, notation

I have inherited Excel files where some of the cell content looks like this:

```
{MY}Jan 2022{/MY} {TY}Webcast{/TY}
```

What is this syntax, and are there programming languages to handle it? It looks like xml except that it uses curly braces instead of angle brackets.

Comment: @d-m I see that you added Excel as tag, note that it is not an Excel question.

Comment: My bad, I assumed that because they were found in an Excel file that they had something to do with an Excel-specific markup. If it's unrelated, please feel free to remove the tag.

Comment: Closest I've been able to find so far: [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33841196/how-to-match-text-inside-starting-and-closing-curly-brace-the-tags-and-the-spec) mentions shortcodes which also show up in [this question on the WordPress development SE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30364/shortcodes-between-square-and-curly-brackets) though it doesn't look like an exact match since [WordPress only recognizes square bracket shortcodes](https://wordpress.com/support/shortcodes/).